# Bursting Balloons

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, dynamic-programming

This is a [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/burst-balloons/) -

> *Given `n` balloons, indexed from `0` to `n-1`. Each balloon is painted
>   with a number on it represented by array `nums`. You are asked to
>   burst all the balloons. If you burst the balloon `i` you will get
>   `nums[left] * nums[i] * nums[right]` coins. Here `left` and `right`
>   are adjacent indices of `i`. After the burst, the `left` and `right`
>   then become adjacent.*
>
> *Find the maximum coins you can collect by bursting the balloons
>   wisely.*
>
> ***Note -***
>
> - *You may imagine `nums[-1] = nums[n] = 1`. They are not real, therefore, you can not burst them.*
> - *\$0\$ \$≤\$ `n` \$≤\$ \$500\$\$,\$ \$0\$ \$≤\$ `nums[i]` \$≤\$ \$100\$*
>
> ***Example -***
>
> ```
> Input: [3,1,5,8]
>
> Output: 167
>
> Explanation: nums = [3,1,5,8] --> [3,5,8] -->   [3,8]   -->  [8]  --> []
>             coins =   3*1*5     +  3*5*8    +   1*3*8     + 1*8*1   = 167
> ```

Here is my solution to this challenge -

```
# Uses dynamic programming

def max_coins(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    nums = [1] + nums + [1]
    n = len(nums)
    dp = [[0] * n for i in range(n)]
    for j in range(2, n):
        for i in range(j - 2, -1, -1):
            for k in range(i + 1,j):
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j], dp[i][k] + dp[k][j] + nums[i] * nums[j] * nums[k])
    return dp[0][-1]
```

Here is the Leetcode result (70 test cases) -

[image]

So, I would like to know whether I could make this program shorter and more efficient.

Comment: Is code length your primary concern? If I see that code, eliminating the doubly nested for-loop would be mine.

Comment: Well, my main concern is efficiency and it would just be better if it could be made shorter.

Comment: Small things `dp = [[0] * n for i in range(n)]` can be `dp = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]`. By convention in python if we dont use the index variable we just use `_`